# How to add a hook in memcpy function of linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, hook, memcpy

The following are my steps,but it did not work as intended.

linux-3.16-rc2\arch\x86\lib\memcpy_64.S:

changed

```
ENTRY(__memcpy)
ENTRY(memcpy)
...
CFI_ENDPROC
ENDPROC(memcpy)
ENDPROC(__memcpy)
```

to:

```
ENTRY(__memcpy)
ENTRY(x86_memcpy)
...
CFI_ENDPROC
ENDPROC(x86_memcpy)
ENDPROC(__memcpy)
```

linux-3.16-rc2\lib\string.c:

changed

```
#ifndef __HAVE_ARCH_MEMCPY
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count)
{
    char *tmp = dest;
    const char *s = src;

    while (count--)
        *tmp++ = *s++;
    return dest;
}
#endif
```

to:

```
//#ifndef __HAVE_ARCH_MEMCPY
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count)
{
    char *tmp = dest;
    const char *s = src;
    my_hook();
    while (count--)
            *tmp++ = *s++;
    return dest;
}
//#endif
```

delete EXPORT_SYMBOL(memcpy) in arch/x86/kernel/x8664_ksyms_64.c

add test code in linux-3.16-rc2\mm\memcpy_test.c:

```
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
int hook_value = -1;
int test_begin = 0;
void  my_test_begin(void)
{
    char src[128] = {0};
    char dst[128] = {1};
    test_begin = 1;
    mb();
    memcpy((char*)dst,(char*)src,50);
    test_begin = 0;
    mb();
    printk("hook value:%d\n",hook_value);
}

void  my_hook(void)
{
    if(test_begin)
            hook_value=1;
}
```

After invoke my_test_begin, I found hook_value remained -1, it seems that memcpy in my_test_begin has never reached hook_value=1
can anyone help? thx!

Comment: Sometimes, the compiler is optimizing `memcpy` to `__builtin_memcpy`

Comment: Thank you Basile! After I add KBUILD_CFLAGS += -fno-builtin in Makefile,all things go well.

Comment: @user3368448: You might like to add this as an answer to your own question. You could also even accept this answer to tell SO your problem had been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Basile Starynkevitch 
I solve the problem, yes, 'Sometimes, the compiler is optimizing memcpy to __builtin_memcpy'